# How do I get useful data from pyspeedtest results?

Tags: python

As a python novice I am trying to write a script to log my internet connection speed using pyspeedtest but I don't understand what the python3 script returns.  It I run it from the shell it returns the ping, download, and upload speeds in mbps, but the results if run in a python script are in some type of raw data format.  How do I convert these results to the standard mbps?

```
import pyspeedtest
st = pyspeedtest.SpeedTest()
ping = st.ping()
download = st.download()
upload = st.upload()

print('ping: ' + str(ping))
print('download: ' + str(download))
print('upload: ' + str(upload))
```

which returns

```
ping: 20.457208156585693
download: 79367128.02705236
upload: 8458681.882858781
```

If I run pyspeedtest from the shell (almost simultaneously) I get:

```
Ping: 18 ms
Download speed: 27.72 Mbps
Upload speed: 19.79 Mbps
```

I checked out the pyspeedtest.py code but I still could not figure out how to convert the python3 results to useful numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Again, I'm an idiot.  Obviously the pyspeedtest python script returns bps, and the shell returns mbps.  I guess I was running those speed tests too close together (one from shell, the other from within python) and it makes the second result way slower than the first, so the two results showed drastically different speeds and I couldn't figure out how the two were related.  Problem solved, moving on...